# How to join two CSV files by a temporary common column in awk?

Tags: awk

I have two CSV files in the form of

file1

```
A,44
A,21
B,65
C,79
```

file2

```
A,7
B,4
C,11
```

I used `awk` as

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in a){print a[$1]","$2 }' file1.csv file2.csv
```

producing

```
A,44,7
A,21,7
B,65,4
C,79,11
```

`a[$1]` prints the entire line from `file1`. How can I omit the first columns in both files (the first column is only used to match the second columns) to produce:

```
44,7
21,7
65,4
79,11
```

In other words, how can I pass the columns from the first file to the print block, as `$2` does for the second file?

Comment: Your approach won't work if your file contains duplicated keys, e.g. the `A` in your file1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, tested and written on shown samples only.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a){print $2,a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                    ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=OFS=","              ##Setting field and output field separator as comma here.
}
FNR==NR{                  ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file2 is being read.
  a[$1]=$2                ##Creating array a with index $1 and value is $2 from current line.
  next                    ##next will skip all further statement from here.
}
($1 in a){                ##Statements from here will be executed when file1 is being read and it's checking if $1 is present in array a then do following.
  print $2,a[$1]          ##Printing 2nd field and value of array a with index $1 here.
}
' file2 file1             ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Output will be as follows for shown samples.

```
44,7
21,7
65,4
79,11
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** More Generic solution, where considering that your both Input_files could have duplicates in that case it will print 1st value of A in Input_file1 to first value of Input_file2 and so on.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]
  b[$1,++c[$1]]=$2
  next
}
($1 in a){
  print $2,b[$1,++d[$1]]
}
' file2 file1
```

Comment: works perfectly. What is the role of `$2` in `a[$1]=$2` which does the trick? I just want to learn.

Comment: @Googlebot, sure,will add detailed explanation in a min or 2.

Comment: @Googlebot, Added detailed explanation please check it  and lemme know in case of any queries here.

Comment: clever solution (the 2nd), you can omit the `a` array. To check multi-dimension array, you can do `(idx1,idx2,idxN) in mdArray`

Comment: @Kent, Thank you for your encouragement sir, my awk is little old I need to check if multi-dimensional arrays are supported there, cheers :)

Comment: No problem, many awk solutions from you are great! If I didn't remember wrongly, m-d array is awk standard stuff. However, I do'nt know if it is introduced since the very beginning. btw, gawk's `a[i][j]` is also very handy. but forgot its name: multi-array? nested array? or whatever

Comment: @Kent, Thank you sir, you make my day, will take pic of appreciation(since greats speak less, you yourself is all time GREAT in awk :) ) I will check on array thing once I get time cheers :)

Comment: +1 for the nice code with explanation, Ravinder. I've made some corrections, please let me know if I made something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can join them using the join command and chose which fields you want to have in the output:

```
kent$  join -t',' -o 1.2,2.2 file1 file2
44,7                                         
21,7
65,4
79,11
```

Comment: doesn't `join` need sorting before joining? it is not a big deal, but just to make sure.

Comment: @Googlebot no, sorting is not mandatory for join command. Of course, you may want to sort if you expect a sorted joined output.

Comment: Wonderful, your solution works like a charm, but I had to accept the other answer, as the question was specifically about `awk`. Thanks, your simple solution will be a great help.

Comment: @Googlebot No problem.  in this particular case, join is easier, since it handles the dup. cases., R.S.'s awk answer is a smart one.